# How to remove redundant data while displaying in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I am fetching data from three tables.
I want to display these data in jsp page.
My problem is that after join data are redundant

I dont want to display redundant data.

My tables are

```
 create table questions(id integer,title varchar(140),body varchar(2000),
 primary key(id));

 create table question_tags(id integer,tag_name varchar(50),question_id integer,
 primary key(id),foreign key(question_id) references questions(id));


create table answers(id integer,answer varchar(2000),question_id integer,
primary key(id),foreign key(question_id) references questions(id));
```

Query to fetch data

```
SELECT questions.*,`question_tags`.*, `answers`.* 
FROM `questions`
JOIN  `answers` 
ON `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id`
JOIN `question_tags` 
ON `questions`.`id` = `question_tags`.`question_id`
WHERE `questions`.`id` = '1'
```

result after fetching data

```
 ID     TITLE   BODY    TAG_NAME    QUESTION_ID ANSWER
  1     a   hello   java                 1          good
  1     a   hello   java                 1          exellent
  1     a   hello   java                 1          ok
  1     a   hello   mysql                1          good
  1     a   hello   mysql                1          exellent
  1     a   hello   mysql                1          ok
  1         a   hello   jquery               1          good
  1     a   hello   jquery               1          exellent
  1     a   hello   jquery               1          ok
```

Here I am fatching data using result set and showing in jsp

I want to show following data in my jsp

```
  question.id|question.title|question.body|tag_names | answers
      1               a           hello       java        good  
                                              mysql       excellent
                                              jquery      ok
```

This was for only few no of rows.
Here total o/p rows are 1*3*3=9
If data are increased in tables  then duplicate data  are increased how to resolve it.
This is [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9606/21) for above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct` clause with your select statement to get no duplicate records

```
SELECT distinct questions.*,`question_tags`.*, `answers`.* 
FROM `questions`
JOIN  `answers` 
ON `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id`
JOIN `question_tags` 
ON `questions`.`id` = `question_tags`.`question_id`
WHERE `questions`.`id` = '1'
```

**Updated**

```
ResultSet rs = st.execute();   //Assuming that you have the resultset

Set<String> id = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
Set<String> body = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
Set<String> tag_name = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
Set<String> answer = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

while(rs.next())
{
    id.add(rs.getString("id"));
    body.add(rs.getString("body"));
    tag_name.add(rs.getString("tag_name"));
    answer.add(rs.getString("answer"));
}
```

Because of the `LinkedHashSet` only distinct values will be stored. Now you need to iterate to populate your table

**NOTE** : This is limited to a particular question ID

Comment: question.id,question.title,question.body,
  tag_names(java,mysql,jquery)
  answers(good,excellent,ok)  please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9606/21

Comment: You mean to say you want _java, mysql, jquery_ in a single cell and so is the case with _good, excellent, ok_ ??

Comment: This problem i m not able to resolve with joining. If no of rows increases then join data also increases.

Comment: No if it is in different shell then also no problem. but i want only three values not other

Comment: Can you define a sample of your expected result. Kindly update it in your question (sample of desired output)

Comment: question.id(1)
            question.title(a)
            question.body(hello)
            tag_names(java,mysql,jquery)
            answers(good,excellent,ok)
as above i want output all above data should be display at once

Comment: Please see desired output at question

Comment: You need to do processing at your servlet. Get all the values in a Set and then iterate through them to populate your table

Comment: So duplicate value handling should be done by programmatically.

Comment: Can we use stored procedure also to remove this value

Comment: Yes you need to do it Servlet side. See the snippet above I provided that will help you to handle the duplicate values. Read Collection and Sets in JAVA. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Comment: yes you can do that. In a stored procedure use CURSORS to iterate through the resultset and then make the resultset of your own. ie. Get all the multiple values in a cell (separated by a delimited - say comma _','_)

Answer (score 0):

What I was expecting was this

```
SELECT  `questions`.`id` AS  `question_id` ,
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `question_tags`.`tag_name` SEPARATOR ';') 
FROM  `question_tags` 
WHERE  `question_id` =1
) AS  `Tags` ,
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `answers`.`answer` SEPARATOR ';' ) 
FROM  `answers` 
WHERE  `question_id` =1
) AS  `Answers` 
FROM  `questions` 
WHERE  `questions`.`id` =1
```